# Azure Function v4 unable to log into application insights

Tags: c#, azure, function, azure-application-insights

I am having the problem that no entries are showing up in Application Insights from my Azure Function. *APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY* and *APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING* have been established and formally reviewed against Application Insights, confirming their accuracy.  *Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights* is installed and it is a C# Azure Function v4.

The code beneath illustrates the function's structure.

```
       public async Task<IActionResult> xxxx(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
ILogger log)
    {

        log.LogInformation("triggered...)");
}
```

[image]

```
            builder.Services.Configure<TelemetryConfiguration>(config =>
        {
            config.SetAzureTokenCredential(infraCredential);
        });

        builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

        public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        var context = builder.GetContext();

        // using Key Vault, either local dev or deployed
        builder.ConfigurationBuilder
            .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, "appsettings.json"), optional: true,
                reloadOnChange: false)
            .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, $"appsettings.{context.EnvironmentName}.json"),
                optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
            .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, "local.settings.json"), optional: true,
                reloadOnChange: false)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
    }
```

Do you have any suggestions for further areas to review? Thank you.

Comment: Are you doing it in local? .net 6 or 7?

Comment: I have also tried it locally but it does not run in the Azure environment. Using .net 6.

Comment: what are u using .net 6 or .net 7?

Comment: I am using .net 6.

Answer (score 1):

> I have also tried it locally but it does not run in the Azure environment. Using .net 6.

I have reproduced in my environment and below are expected results:

Firstly disconnected local and connected application insights in portal as below:

[image]

Then connected as below:

[image]

Click on next to finish steps(in next steps select your application insights resource)

Then after you will get to see something like this :

[image]

**`Function1.cs:`**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;

namespace FunctionApp81
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly TelemetryClient telcl;

        public Function1(TelemetryClient teleyClient)
        {
            telcl = teleyClient;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik , I am From logger.");
            telcl.TrackEvent("Hello Rithwik how are you from telemetry client");
            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "Hello Rithwik plz pass a name"
                : $"Hello, {name}. ";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

**`local.settings.json:`**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "32260fba-8fd2-d146"
  }
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`In portal:`**

[image]

Telemetry client output:

[image]

Try to follow above steps to get required result as I have got. You can also deploy to Azure and run it, then also you will get(do not forget to add the connection string in Environment variables section).